# how do I put the index of the matching elements into a list?

Tags: prolog

I just started learning prolog, and came across this problem where I am trying to input the index of matching elements from an initial list, to a new list. For example, I have a list of Y = [[a], [b], [c], [d], [a,a], [b,b], [c]], and I am trying to find the occurrence of X = [c], and put the index where [c] is, into a new list.

```
find( X, [ X | Y ], N) :-
    find(X, Y, N1), N is N1 +1.
find( X, [ H | Y ], N ) :-
    find( X, Y, N).
```

My N only shows the number of occurrences, which N = 2.
But I would like the output to be N = [3,7].
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to have a list as Result you will need another variable into your predicate.

First let me show you the solution:

```
find(_,[],_,[]).
find(X,[X|L],N,[N|R]):-
    N1 is N+1,
    find(X,L,N1,R).
find(X,[_|L],N,R):-
    N1 is N+1,
    find(X,L,N1,R).
```

Now you should call it like:

```
?- find([c],[[a],[b],[c],[d],[a,a],[b,b],[c]],1,R).
```

and you will get the following result:

```
R = [3, 7]
```

I hope you understand the solution. It stores the current index in `N` and puts it back in `R` if the current item is the one you are looking for.